# Change text in datagrid in databound, in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf datagrid,

Here's my datagrid

```
<dg:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
             ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource columnHeaderStyle}"
             AlternationCount="2" RowBackground="Beige"
             RowStyle="{StaticResource rowStyle}"
             AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" 

             HeadersVisibility="All"
             HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#DDDDDD"
             VerticalGridLinesBrush="#DDDDDD" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,26" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnHeaderHeight="30">

            <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header=" Task Id" Binding="{Binding Path=TaskId}" Width="60" />
                <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Description" Binding="{Binding Path=OrderDescription}"  Width="120"/>
                <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Final Client Name" Binding="{Binding Path=ClientName}"  Width="110"/>
                <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Binding="{Binding Path=OrderDate}"  Width="80"/>
                <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Task Description" Binding="{Binding Path=TaskDescription}"  Width="130"/>
                <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Name Short" Binding="{Binding Path=GroupNameShort}"  Width="116"/>
                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn  MinWidth="100" Header=" Actions">
                    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Click="DetailButton_Click">Close</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        </dg:DataGrid>
```

In aspx to change text we use onrowdatabound  for example, here in wpf how can I change the field *Order Description* and *Order Date*.
I have two functions to change the text, that are convertDatetimeToDate(string datetime) e htmltotext(string text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a value converter on the binding.  Create a class that implements [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), and set an instance of that class as the Converter property of the binding.

```
public class DateTimeToDateConverter
    : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Call convertDatetimeToDate here and return the result
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your XAML, create an instance of the converter.  You may need to add a namespace reference:

```
<Window.Resources xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace">
    <local:DateTimeToDateConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it in the binding:

```
<dg:DataGridTextColumn
    Header="Order Date"
    Binding="{Binding Path=OrderDate, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"
    Width="80"/>
```

In 3.5 SP1 or later, you can also use the StringFormat property on the binding to do simple formatting.  This should format the datetime as a plain date by doing the equivalent of `string.Format("{0:d}", OrderDate)`:

```
<dg:DataGridTextColumn
    Header="Order Date"
    Binding="{Binding Path=OrderDate, StringFormat='{}{0:d}'}"
    Width="80"/>
```